# Can't reference an Excel worksheet in teams from another worksheet

Tags: excel, reference, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, excel-365

I have shared worksheet stored in Teams. I want to reference some data in that sheet from another worksheet.

ref.xlsx - a reference worksheet stored in Teams and shared with everybody.
work.xlsx - a summary of work data stored on my OneDrive and shared with others.

Assume a reference in work.xlsx to a cell in ref.xlsx like so:

```
='[ref.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

This works fine as long as ref.xlsx is opened in the Excel app. Once I close it, the references stop working and I get a #REF error in work.xlsx.

It's not manageable to expect people to have to open all the worksheets that will be referenced. This seems like a huge issue with storing Excel files in Teams.

I hope I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: can you clarify if the described functionality works in excel online ?
i as as the  term `excel app` can refer to either excel online, the desktop app or the  mobile app

Comment: I would try uploading the same worksheets in sharepoint/Teams, get the references and add it to see if it helps

Comment: @JosVerlinde Hi Jos. It does work with Excel online.

Comment: @dev Are you suggesting I use the Sharepoint reference to the file rather than the Teams reference? I'll give that a try.

Comment: Sure @DavidRichardson. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: just to clarify : Teams files = Sharepoint. 
however teams has a 'built-in' excel app. if you find that your formula works Excel online , but not in the teams embedded Excel app, then i suggest that you report that as a bug via [? Help] > Feedback

Comment: @DavidRichardson, is it the case as Jos mentioned that formulas works on excel online but not in Teams excel?

Comment: @abhijit Yes, that is the case.

Comment: @Dev Sorry for the late reply. Works great if I reference the same sheet from Sharpoint. It's very odd. If I open the sheet from Teams and reference it doesn't work. If I open from Sharepoint and reference it, it works fine. It's the same sheet.

Comment: @JosVerlinde I'm using Office 365, which I assume is what you mean by online? The issue not in the Teams excel apps. It's with a reference to sheet that was opened from Teams.

Comment: @DavidRichardson - thanks for the update. Sounds like the reference is not identified when you tried to access it from Teams. BTW, i tested with latest Teams and i failed to repro the issue. Not sure if i missing any steps...

Comment: When you link from A to B (files, both open), then close A, does the reference stay '[ref.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1, or does the long path name of the OneDrive location / other appear?  Also - if you select the cell once A is closed, press F2 and enter (or highlight and press F9, before escaping) does the result change? Finally, if you press alt + e + k (Edit links), and update all, any difference?